# jquery submit empty form after ajax success

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to submit form after ajax success, but after ajax jquery submit form with empty values.
basically i work in codeigniter and want to authorize a sandbox authorize.net transaction. my code is

```
<?php echo form_open('', array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'validate-form')); ?>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Payment/Authorization Information</legend>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <div id="test2"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="number" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Card Number:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" id="number" placeholder="enter number without spaces" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="code" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Card Code:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" placeholder="enter card code" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="eDate" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Expiration Date:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="eDate" placeholder="mmyy" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
      if($price){
        $price = $price[0]->price;
      }
    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="amount" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Product Price:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dAmount" value="<?=$price?> $" readonly required>
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="amount" value="<?=$price?>" required>
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="refTransId" id="refTransId" value="" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
        <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){

  if($('#validate-form').valid()){
    var postData = $('#validate-form').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>product/authCard',
    data: postData,
    beforeSend: function()
    {
      $('#submit').append(' ... <img src="<?=base_url()?>images/loader.gif" width="25px" height="" alt="loader.gif" />');
    },
    success: function(data){
      var test = $.parseJSON(data);
      if(test.responseCode == 1)
      {
        $('#refTransId').val(test.transId);
        $('#validate-form').attr('action', '<?=base_url()?>product/authenticate');
        $('#validate-form').submit();


        // $('#test').html('<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>' +test.description + ' AUTH CODE: ' +test.authCode+ ', TRANS ID: ' +test.transId                                                                +'. </div>');
      }
      else
      {
        $('#test').html('<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>      An Error has been occured. Error code : ' +test.errorCode + ', Error Text : ' +test.errorText+ '. </div>');
      }
      $('#submit').html('Submit');
    }           

  });
  }

});
```

Comment: how so you know you ajax is triggering ??

Comment: my form is submitted to the url specified but with empty form fields

Comment: how do you know the fields are empty and what type of request are you doing?

Comment: in controller <?=base_url()?>product/authenticate there is no form field and request type is post

Answer (score 1):

Add the action directly to your page with php

```
echo form_open('product/authenticate', array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'validate-form'));
```

Comment: $('#submit') is not a button type submit

Comment: ajax triggering successfully and return  a refTransId number. after ajax success form submitted to specified url but with empty form fields

Comment: @ArifSami you could Just change the selecor, and try it Right?

Comment: @ArifSami how do you know they are empty?

Comment: in controller <?=base_url()?>product/authenticate there is no form field

Comment: when you do var_dump($_REQUEST) in <?=base_url()?>product/authenticate what do you get?

Comment: array(1) { ["/product/authenticate"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: why are you changing the action of the form with jquery?

Comment: if not change action the form submit on this page even if action is specified in html form action attribute.

Comment: all i want to submit the form with form values

Comment: thy removing the reset button and submitting it that way

Answer (score 1):

I see there are two issues in your code

1. you have not returned false in the `click` function to stop next event propagation.
2. in ajax success response you have submitted the form again

So modified code should be like as below.

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e){

    if($('#validate-form').valid()){
        var postData = $('#validate-form').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>product/authCard',
            data: postData,
            beforeSend: function()
            {
              $('#submit').append(' ... <img src="<?=base_url()?>images/loader.gif" width="25px" height="" alt="loader.gif" />');
            },
            success: function(data){
                var test = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(test.responseCode == 1)
                {
                $('#refTransId').val(test.transId);
                $('#validate-form').attr('action', '<?=base_url()?>product/authenticate');

                // $('#test').html('<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>' +test.description + ' AUTH CODE: ' +test.authCode+ ', TRANS ID: ' +test.transId                                                                +'. </div>');
                }
                else
                {
                $('#test').html('<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>      An Error has been occured. Error code : ' +test.errorCode + ', Error Text : ' +test.errorText+ '. </div>');
                }
                $('#submit').html('Submit');
            }
        });
    }
    return false;

});
```

Comment: ajax checks given form fields to be valid and return an additional value refTranId. all i want is if ajax success form should be submitted to <?=base_url()?>product/authenticate'